# Edit/Delete Google Calendar Events and get event Id

Tags: android, android-intent, google-calendar-api, android-contentprovider

I am trying to edit and delete events in Google calendar using Calendar Provider. I have already Created event using Calendar Provider .

Here is my code to create an event :

```
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    beginTime.set(2014, 5, 19, 7, 30);
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(2014, 5, 19, 8, 30);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "")
            .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "")
            .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "")
            .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
    startActivity(intent);
```

event is getting created successfully. now i want to edit/delete the event. so, how can i perform this. And for edit/delete i need event id for created event how i can get that??

Please... help me guys.

Comment: Check this url [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223107/update-and-delete-calendar-events-in-android-through-my-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223107/update-and-delete-calendar-events-in-android-through-my-application) Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the help but

If i was using 
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "America/Los_Angeles");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

to insert an event into calendar thi ling would have helped me out but here i am using Intents to insert into calendar. so it will not work out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update and delete calendar events in android through my application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223107/update-and-delete-calendar-events-in-android-through-my-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this url

[Update and delete calendar events in android through my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223107/update-and-delete-calendar-events-in-android-through-my-application)

Hope it helps :)

Get Event Id :

```
private int ListSelectedCalendars(String eventtitle) {


    Uri eventUri;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
        // the old way

        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    } else {
        // the new way

        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    }

    int result = 0;
    String projection[] = { "_id", "title" };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(eventUri, null, null, null,
            null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String calName;
        String calID;

        int nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
        int idCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        do {
            calName = cursor.getString(nameCol);
            calID = cursor.getString(idCol);

             if (calName != null && calName.contains(eventtitle)) {
            result = Integer.parseInt(calID);
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }

    return result;

}
```

Update Event :

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private int UpdateCalendarEntry(int entryID) {
    int iNumRowsUpdated = 0;

    Uri eventUri;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
        // the old way

        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    } else {
        // the new way

        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    }

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.TITLE, "test");
    values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Chennai");

    Uri updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventUri, entryID);
    iNumRowsUpdated = getContentResolver().update(updateUri, values, null,
            null);

    return iNumRowsUpdated;
}
```

Delete Event :

```
    private int DeleteCalendarEntry(int entryID) {
    int iNumRowsDeleted = 0;

    Uri eventUri = ContentUris
            .withAppendedId(getCalendarUriBase(), entryID);
    iNumRowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(eventUri, null, null);

    return iNumRowsDeleted;
}

private Uri getCalendarUriBase() {
    Uri eventUri;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
        // the old way

        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    } else {
        // the new way

        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    }

    return eventUri;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shini,i have used your code to update event and it is updating but don't know event is changing it's day. For example if i create event on 13th day it after update event it's day is 12.Do you have any idea about it.